# Website isn't sending emails outside of domain

Tags: email

I have a website 'dementeddinosaw.ga' and I am having a problem with sending emails from my web mail.

I can only send emails to accounts within the same domain.

Example: I can send an email from admin@dementeddinosaw.ga to info@dementeddinosaw.ga but I can't send emails to addresses outside of the domain e.g.(myemail@gmail.com).

I can receive emails from any domain, but I can only send to emails within dementeddinosaw.ga

Any Help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the whole IP-range your mail-server is hosted in has been blacklisted by spamhaus.org (see the [blocklist entry](https://www.spamhaus.org/sbl/query/SBL278598)).

So any mial-hosters using this blacklist to protect themselves from spam will reject any messages coming from mx.dementeddinosaw.ga

The only way to have this entry removed seems to be for your hosting-provider to contact spamhaus.